# Removing one's account

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

Can you tell me if a user who removes his account at one site, can after some time open a new account?

In this case can he use the same email address for signing in, and should notify someone?

I am not planning to go/come back, I want to know if deleting an account at one site (especially if one keeps other accounts) is really absolutely irreversible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Account deletion is irreversible, you will lose all your associated posts, badges and reputation. While SE developers can manually restore an account partially, this is pretty much only done now when the deletion was an error or mistake of some kind.

You can create a new account using the same mail address after you deleted your old one, but you won't get back any of your old reputation or badges. If you're deleting accounts to circumvent any restrictions on your old account, e.g. a question or answer ban, expect to run into certain automatic mechanisms that will block you from posting.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was asking, one loses **that** account, but can get a new account anyway and ask questions. So it's only the loss of rep that is irreversible.

Comment: Loss of rep, badges and privileges.